# Spotify API/ADK For Android

Tags: android, spotify, libspotify

Is there any Spotify API/SDK available for Android. I have checked on their web site but got the Zip file which contain c code.After searching more on this topic I come to know that to access the c code I have to go for JNI way which I want to avoid.

So I just want to know that is there any API/SDK available which I can use as I want to integrate Spotify in my Android App.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no other Spotify API apart from Libspotify. It's targetted for more advanced developers.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst LotusUNSW's answer is correct it is worth asking, what are you looking to achieve with your Spotify integration?

If you just want to query/lookup information about artists/albums/tracks then you can use the [Spotify Web API](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/web-api/) calling their web services and deserializing the returned JSON/XML in your app.